# 32-bit context menu application not showing in 64-bit Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, 64-bit, context-menu

I have a VB6 application which pops up on the context menu of an E-Document. This works correctly on a 32-bit OS (i.e. on right mouse click of a text file, the application is displayed for selection). On 64-bit Windows 7, it doesn't show there.

This application uses APIs for adding the option to the Windows Registry and for displaying the same in the Context Menu option. Please let me know, if anything further is required to make this show in the 64-bit version of the OS.

Answer (score 5):

64-bit Windows Explorer can't load 32-bit shell extension .DLLs. Use a 64-bit shell extension, or [try running 32-bit Windows Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895561) from `%windir%\Syswow64`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Tool called [WOW64Menu](http://www.gasanov.net/WOW64Menu.asp) which opens the 32Bit contextmenu entries.

Answer (score 0):

**A 64-bit process can only load 64-bit DLLs.**

You must either recompile the program as 64-bit or run the 32-bit explorer in `%windir%\SysWOW64`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a 32-bit file browser that supports shell extensions. I don't know that the 64-bit version of Windows 7 has a 32-bit explorer, so that's probably out of the question (unless you're running an old pre-release version). However, you can install something like [Explorer++](http://explorerplusplus.com/), 32-bit edition. Good luck!